# How to implement database first approach in Nest JS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nodejs-server, nestjs-config, nestjs-gateways

I have three schemas(User, Account, Contact) these three schemas used to created a model and generate the migration files also Next, this migration file migrate the PostgreSQL Database this part successfully completed using Nest JS.

Next, Manually I created one table and added few columns in the table. In this table(model) I need automatically integrate in our Nest JS CODE is it possible?

So, I google it how to achieve this scenario this given one solution **schema first approach**.

In Nest JS used one Library that is **GraphQL** this library used to achieve **schema first approach**. I
tried this approach but I could not get the database model in our code.

Anyone tell me how to achieve this scenario

Answer (score 0):

/*Combining NestJS and Prisma provides a new level of type-safety that is impossible to achieve with any other ORM from the Node.js & TypeScript ecosystem. This example demonstrates how to use Prisma Client.*/

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit, INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient
implements OnModuleInit {

async onModuleInit() {
 await this.$connect();
}

async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
     await app.close();
    });    
  }
}
```